# testng.xml is skipping tests?

Tags: java, selenium, servlets, testng

So I have some tests written that run successfully if I either run it directly as a TestNG test or if I run the testng.xml file that holds the test.  But currently I am trying to call the TestNG run method when I make a request to my Java servlet.  I use a custom reporter to write the results to a json file, and send those results back in the response.

However, whenever I make a request to the servlet, the results I get sent back tell me that all of my tests are being skipped.  Why would my tests run successfully when accessed directly, and just skip when being called by TestNG.run() ?

Here is my testng.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="MyTestSuite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="util.Listener"></listener>
        <listener class-name="util.JsonReporter"></listener>
    </listeners>
    <test name="TestOne">
        <classes>
            <class name="testngs.MyTest"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And a short dummy test:

```
package testngs;

import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pages.MyPage;

public class MyTest {

    public static MyPage myPage;
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUpDriverAndPage() {
        File file = new File("src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        myPage = new ManageBatchPage(driver);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void createBatch() throws InterruptedException {
        // filler code

        Assert.assertEquals("hello", "hello");

    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void cleanup() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

And my servlet code:

```
if (uri.equals("/TestProject/getTests.do")) {       
    TestNG runner = new TestNG();
    List<String> suiteFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    suiteFiles.add(/*path to my xml*/);
    runner.setTestSuites(suiteFiles);
    runner.run();

    // read results from json file
    JsonArray testResults = ResultParser.parseJson();

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().print(testResults);
}
```

Comment: Hmm I'm looking at the TestNG api.... Try calling `runner.runSuites()` instead of `run()`

Comment: ...That should return a one-item list containing a `ISuite` object, which you can call `getMethodsByGroup()` on.  Then you can confirm that your test suite methods are in fact being parsed by the runner.  The Java debugger will be helpful here, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, but not elegantly. Turns out that my test file doesn't like the path of my webdriver when it's ran from the server, but works fine when i run the file directly.  Gonna have to make a properties file or something that holds the absolute path for when I run it on the server.